# $(a^{2^n}+1,a^{2^m}+1)=1 or 2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

> Prove that if $m\not =n,a$ are positive integers then $(a^{2^n}+1,a^{2^m}+1)$ is $1$ if $a$ is even and $2$ if $a$ is odd.

I solve the problem in the following way: I assume that $m>n$ then 
$$a^{2^m}+1=a^{2^m}-1+2$$
With this expression if I take a divisor prime $p$ of $a^{2^n}+1$ then if $p|a^{2^m}+1$ this prime must divide 2 and the result follows.

But, how can I prove this statement without use of primes? This exercise appears before the concept of prime is introduced then I prefer do not use it.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: There's an $m \neq n$ constraint missing.

Comment: If $m≠n$ then it is true. Do you have any idea about Fermat numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we have $n < m$, then

$$(a^{2^n} + 1)\cdot (a^{2^n} - 1) = a^{2^{n+1}} - 1$$

shows $(a^{2^n}+1) \mid (a^{2^{n+1}}-1)$. Then

$$(a^{2^k}-1)\cdot(a^{2^k}+1) = a^{2^{k+1}}-1$$

shows $(a^{2^{n+1}}-1) \mid (a^{2^m}-1)$, and thus

$$\gcd(a^{2^m}+1, a^{2^n}+1) = \gcd((a^{2^m}-1)+2,a^{2^n}+1) = \gcd(2, a^{2^n}+1).$$

Comment: Jmmm... If $a|c$ then $gcd(a+b,c)=gcd(b,c)$? Thanks!

Comment: If $c\mid a$, not if $a\mid c$. If we write $a = k\cdot c$, it becomes $\gcd(a+b,c) = \gcd(a+b-kc,c) = \gcd(b,c)$.